# jQuery how paste new value from <td> with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have table that is static value and I want to add dynamically from JSON file value only to cell (td) with `class="rxlevel"`

```
<table id='scores' border="1" style="border: 1px #aaa solid">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Pocet</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RxLevel</td>
        <td class="rxlevel"></td>
        <td class="rxlevel"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>3/2/2014</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>6/6/2013</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RxLevel2</td>
        <td class="rxlevel"></td>
        <td class="rxlevel"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and JS script:

```
var timer = $.timer(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url/for/json/file",
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function (data) {
        $(data.scores).each($('.rxlevel'), function (index, element) {
            $('#scores').append('<tr><td> ' + element[0] + ' </td> <td> ' + element[1] + '</td></tr>');
        });
    });
});
timer.set({
    time: 5000,
    autostart: true
});
```

If I remove *`$('.rxlevel')`* from `$.each` function after 5 second are appended new data. Is is correct.

JSON file:

```
{
 "scores": 
 [ 
    ["18/1/2011", 610],
    ["4/1/2011", 610],
    ["5/1/2011", 610],
    ["6/1/2011", 610], 
    ["7/1/2011", 720], 
    ["8/1/2011", 500], 
    ["9/1/2011", 500] 
 ]
}
```

I want to add to **td** cell (with `class="rxlevel"`) data from JSON. Can you help me?

Thanks.

My idea:

```
<table id='scores' border="1" style="border: 1px #aaa solid">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Pocet</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RxLevel</td>
        <td class="rxlevel">18/1/2011</td>
        <td class="rxlevel">610</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>3/2/2014</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>6/6/2013</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RxLevel2</td>
        <td class="rxlevel">4/1/2011</td>
        <td class="rxlevel">610</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try a success handler like `$('.rxlevel').text(function (i) {
            return data.scores[Math.floor(i / 2)][Math.floor(i / 2) + (i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)]
        })`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c6xnm0fv/4/

Comment: @MelanciaUK: it is correct competely. In the table are some cell without class="rxlevel". This class is assigned manually for selected cell.

Comment: So you want to keep those _hardcoded_ rows (the ones without class) and generate the others dynamically based on the data coming through?

Comment: I dont know I understand your answer exactly. I want to data from JSON only to **cell with assigned class**. Class is assigned manually. Others are static data (any rewrite).

Comment: But then, your JSON data is returning more values (7) than your table can fit (2).

Comment: Yes, it is truth. Redundant values can be removed from JSON.